# does SSLVPN make your http request encrypted?

Tags: security, ssl, vpn, public-key-encryption, tor

As a logically I know the answer but I couldn't find any resource on google to clarify my confusing.

I know when you connect to a VPN all your requests is going to VPN through ISP's and routers.

My goal is make the all requests and responses which is incoming or outgoing from my computer must be encrypted with SSL.

That will protect my data from ISP's or any MITM attacks or any dns / tcp sniffing.

When I request any content from http://www.example.com it is not encrypted if I use direct internet and if there is MITM then all my data will captured by the attacker, or with tor, if exit node is capturing the tcp data again my privacy will broke.

So if I use an anonymous tor + ssl vpn or just ssl vpn and if I connect to http://example.com and if there is MITM or any sniffing among the routing or in ISP's, can they see any data non-encrypted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to http://www.example.com (e.g. non-SSL) through any type of VPN (e.g. it does not matter if SSL based, IPSec, Tor...) it will only protect the connection between the VPN endpoints, e.g. your computer and the other VPN endpoint somewhere on the internet. From there the connection to your final target (www.example.com) host is unprotected.  Only if the target system is the endpoint of the VPN your connection will be end-to-end protected.

Comment: oh! actually I just missed that step. So if the case would be the target link https://example.com and if there would be any attacker in target system then there is no chance to prevent my request from attack either is ssl or not ? that I correct ?

Comment: If the attacker has compromised the target system your data are unsafe anyway. What I refer to is that between the VPN endpoint and the target are other systems, e.g. If you are in UK and use a VPN with an endpoint in the US and then access a website in Japan through this VPN there are lots of systems between the VPN endpoint in US and the target system in Japan which could snoop the unprotected traffic.